# I have two versions of testng, how do I remove the older version and prevent dependencies conflicts

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, testng

Basically I'm running sbt gen-idea for a project which I'm using Intellij to develop. Whenever I run the "sbt gen-idea" command, I get this warning continuously throughout the process. The only problem is the command line doesn't stop running so I'm not able to select a version at the time. Within my project I have the xml file with the dependencies set to use testng version 6.9.10, however still this proves to be a problem.

Anyone know how I can either remove the older version or stop this conflict from occurring.

Thanks in advance for any help

```
[warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
[warn]  * org.testng:testng:(6.9.10, 6.8.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find which dependency is using old version of testNG using `mvn dependency:tree` (refer to this [page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) for more details)

After that try to exclude it from dependency using `<exclusions><exclusion></exclusion></exclusions>` refer to this [page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)